# Using both multiclassing systems at once

Tags: pathfinder-1e, multi-classing

Pathfinder enables regular multiclassing (taking levels in multiple classes) as well as variant multiclassing (substituting feat slots for class levels). I was thinking of making a character who does both of these, taking multiple levels in different classes and spending feat slots for variant multiclassing. Is this possible?

Comment: there is also one third variant there, if also old things from d20 are n your group: Gestalt

Answer (score 7):

It is; variant multiclassing uses up your feats, and does not care what your “actual” class levels are doing. The one caveat is that you cannot take actual levels in the class you choose for variant multiclassing. Paizo recommends against using both, however. As with any variant system, you should speak to your GM about whether or not you can use it, and whether or not you can use it the way you want to.

> It is probably a good idea to use either this variant system or normal multiclassing, but it's possible for the two systems to be used together. In a game using both systems, a character can't take levels in the secondary class she gains from this variant.

Beyond this suggestion, allow me to also offer my own recommendation: never use variant multiclassing at all. Not a single one of them is *even remotely* worth what you can get with the five feats that you give up. Most of them are insultingly poor, in fact.

Comment: I'd say that some of them can be worth it if you know why you take them and plan it right. Especially for characters who get bonus feats from their class.

Comment: @Umbranus No, none of them are worth five feats. Few of them are worth two. The *concept* of VMC is perfectly sound—it’s a great idea!—but the actual VMCs themselves are absurdly, pitifully weak for the cost. Which is a real shame, because they set precedent for all future VMCs, so we’ll probably never get a decent one.

Comment: I quite like the Bard VMC from the looks of it, though I haven't played it yet. Figure with the Banner of the ancient kings I get rid of the lvl-4 for inspire courage... - but I am struggling really hard to fit all the combat feats I was planning on using into the build...

Comment: @Julix Nope, it’s not. Every. single. VMC. is *always*, **100% of the time**, a trap. Feats are massively valuable. Half your feats is an absurd investment to make into *anything*. The 7th-level VMC bard feature is worth a feat, possibly even more than a feat, but all of the rest are worth way, way less than a feat, and while that 7th-level feature **might** be worth two feats, it is nowhere close to being worth **five**.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I guess the way I see it is I'm not playing at level 20. At level 9 I've given up two feats for other things I really like. - I guess I didn't consider how long the lifespan of this char might be and how it becomes a worse deal over time basically. --- What about a Slayer VMC Rogue (5 feats for 4d6 sneak, trap finding, evasion and uncanny dodge - seems to be a good deal to me? and Slayer gets enough bonus feats to make it workable)

Comment: @Julix It’s better than most—2d6 sneak attack damage isn’t a bad feat, so 4d6 is decent for two, and evasion and uncanny dodge are each roughly worth a feat maybe (uncanny dodge more so), so that gets you to 4. Trap finding is garbage not worth remembering you have, honestly, though, so you definitely don’t get to 5 feats’ worth of value. Still, 4/5 is better than any other VMC option I can think of. Problem is that sneak attack builds need a lot of feats to function (archery or two-weapon fighting lines) which makes it really hard to give up half your feats. You can do better.